# Android studio is freezing on indexing when I'm importing a feature module using 'implementation' in the main module(app)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

So, I have this module `auth` with three dynamic feature modules.

[image]

But when I'm trying to import this `auth_data` in the app Gradle(`build.gradle`) file android studio is freezing on 'indexing' after Gradle build.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is there a module `auth_data` inside module `auth`? If yes then why not use `auth_data` directly. In the case if `auth_data` module is dependent on `auth` the just implement the `auth` module.

Comment: i have roughly the same problem i think, i converted a static library module to dynamic, made all changes then AStudio freezes i cannot do anything.

Comment: We are also having the same problem.